# Oracle Real Application Clusters で手動フェイルオーバーの実施方法を知りたい

Tags: oracle

OracleDB:Oracle 12cR1(12.1.0.2.0)
OS:Oracle Linux 7.9

node1:192.168.56.101 (Public), 192.168.100.101 (Private), 192.168.200.101 (Private)

node2:192.168.56.102 (Public), 192.168.100.102 (Private), 192.168.200.102 (Private)

dns:192.168.56.254 (Public)　※bind

現在RAC環境は問題なく稼働しています。そこで、フェイルオーバー試験を実施したいのですが、単純にどうやればいいですか。Data Guard環境ではスイッチオーバー、フェイルオーバー等の実施経験があるのですが、RACの場合、node1に異常が起こったと想定しフェイルオーバーさせる場合、単純にnode1のサーバ自体を落とせば良いのですか。あるいはフェイルオーバーさせるためのコマンドが存在しますか。

最後に、Data Guard環境ですと、スタンバイからフェイルオーバーさせると元プライマリを再作成してロールを入れ替えて（スイッチオーバー）と、元の構成に戻すまでにかなり面倒ですが、RACの場合はどうなんでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 現在RAC環境は問題なく稼働しています。そこで、フェイルオーバー試験を実施したいのですが、単純にどうやればいいですか。

単純に考えるとRACで多重化されているネットワーク、サーバ、ストレージを１つだけ残して他をすべて落せばよいと思います。
RACの機能自体を試験するのであればサーバのOracleインスタンスを一部だけKillしたり、メモリ不足を発生させるプログラムを起動したり、いろいろと考えなければいけないと思いますが、そこまで試験する必要がないなら単に落とせばよいと思います。

> RACの場合、node1に異常が起こったと想定しフェイルオーバーさせる場合、単純にnode1のサーバ自体を落とせば良いのですか。あるいはフェイルオーバーさせるためのコマンドが存在しますか。

そのようなコマンドはないと思います。※RAC自身が異常検知をしなければ意味がないと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。では単純にnode1のoracleユーザからsqlplusでインスタンスを落とすだけでもよいということでしょうか。

Comment: はい、単純なテストであればそれでよいと思います。